# Refresh Token Cookie returns null value when using chrome or IE Edge, but not on postman

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, refresh-token

**Update:** The browser my have made me unable to set the cookie because i was to 'aggressive' setting it on testing. All it took was a restart of my computer. Hopes this can clarify for other in the same situation.

---

I have made a web api using C# and .net 7, and I have an endpoint, which is generating and setting a refresh token cookie. When I login using swagger UI in chrome and IE Edge, the cookie has stop being set. But when I use PostMan to test my API endpoints, it is set correctly.

Any thoughts of what is going on?

My Refresh-token service methods looks like this

```
private const string RefreshTokenCookieName = "refresh-token";

// Constructor and other methods is hidden

public RefreshToken GenerateRefreshToken()
{
    var refreshToken = new RefreshToken
    {
        Token = Convert.ToBase64String(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(64)),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
    };

    return refreshToken;
}

public void SetRefreshToken(RefreshToken refreshToken, User user)
{
    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Expires = refreshToken.Expires,
    };

    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Response.Cookies.Append(RefreshTokenCookieName, refreshToken.Token, cookieOptions);

    user.RefreshToken = refreshToken.Token;
    user.RefreshTokenCreated = refreshToken.DateTimeCreated;
    user.RefreshTokenExpires = refreshToken.Expires;
}

public string GetRefreshTokenCookie()
{
    return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Cookies[RefreshTokenCookieName]!;
}
```

Refresh Token handler

```
public async Task<string> Handle(RefreshTokenQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;

    var refreshToken = _jwtTokenService.GetRefreshTokenCookie();
    var user = _userRepository.GetUserByUsername(request.Username);

    if (!user!.RefreshToken.Equals(refreshToken))
    {
        throw new RefreshTokenInvalidException();
    }
    else if (user!.RefreshTokenExpires < DateTime.UtcNow)
    {
        throw new RefreshTokenExpiredException();
    }
    else
    {
        var token = _jwtTokenService.GenerateToken(user);
        var newRefreshToken = _jwtTokenService.GenerateRefreshToken();
        _jwtTokenService.SetRefreshToken(newRefreshToken, user);

        return token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making a fetch request on chrome/edge?

Comment: Whether you visit `https` or `http` in the browser, you have set `HttpOnly`. Are there any error messages?

Comment: Thx for the answers. I choose to sleep on it, and therefore I turned off my pc. The next morning it all worked as intended. I think the browsers somehow found my testing a little to aggressively, and therefore I couldnt set it. So all it took was a restart of my PC. Silly me :D